# Unable to parse TOML file even after setting struct tags

Tags: go, toml

I installed dependency using:

```
go get github.com/BurntSushi/toml
```

I created a toml file in the same folder as my `main.go`:

```
.
|-- cloud.toml
`-- main.go
```

#### cloud.toml

```
[database]
host = "localhost"
port = 8086
secure = false
username = "test"
password = "password"
dbName = "test"
```

#### main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/BurntSushi/toml"
)

type tomlConfig struct {
    DB dbInfo
}

type dbInfo struct {
    Host string `toml:"host"`
    Port int    `toml: "port"`
    Secure bool `toml: "secure"`
    Username string `toml: "username"`
    Password string `toml: "password"`
    DbName string `toml:"dbName"`
}

func main() {
    var dbConfig tomlConfig

    if _, err := toml.DecodeFile("cloud.toml", &dbConfig); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Database Configuration")
    fmt.Printf("Host: %s\n", dbConfig.DB.Host)
    fmt.Printf("Port: %d\n", dbConfig.DB.Port)


}
```

#### Output

```
go run main.go

Database Configuration
Host:
Port: 0
```

What am I doing wrong here?

my `go env` is:

```
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\des\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\des\go
set GOPROXY=
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=C:\Go
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GCCGO=gccgo
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\des\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build309995570=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the appropriate toml tag to your struct:

```
type tomlConfig struct {
     DB dbInfo `toml:"database"`
}
```

You should also remove the spaces from your other tags, to make them valid:

```
type dbInfo struct {
    Host     string `toml:"host"`
    Port     int    `toml:"port"`
    Secure   bool   `toml:"secure"`
    Username string `toml:"username"`
    Password string `toml:"password"`
    DbName   string `toml:"dbName"`
}
```

Comment: strange enough the marshalling isn't working. However if I change the tag in the TOML file to `DB` then it works.

Comment: @Shan-Desai You didn't do as I suggested. You still have spaces in your tags, rendering them invalid.